# should add_timer and del_timer appear in pairs?

Tags: linux, timer, kernel

Under linux kernel development, should add_timer and del_timer appear in pairs? It means, should I call del_timer() after the timer expires ? Or del_timer() should be called when the module is unloaded.

Comment: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-4

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-timers-list/